# Retrieve multiple datab by synchronization from Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying send my contacts to firebase one by one and checking if the user is present or not but due to the asynchronous behavior of firebase some information is showing twice.

I want to synchronize this method like this:

loop send one number to firebase, firebase response, save, and continue

```
    for (int i=0 ; i< list.size();i++) {

                    Check_Contact(list.get(i)); 

         }
```

```
 public void Check_Contact(String number)
        {
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("user").child(number);
            myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {


                    }
                    else {
                        UserProfile row = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
                        ls.add(row);
                        Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }

            });
```

Can somebody tell me how to synchronize this method?

**Firebase Structure**

[image: Firebase Structure]

**output coming**

[image: output coming]

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: both are attached

Answer (score 0):

It is not the firebase async behaviour. You may have duplicate contents in your database. Please check ur database and update a screenshot of your database in your question.

It will be more helpful to understand your question.

Comment: both are attached

Comment: ino it's not my contact problem i am doing another method retrieve all contact then compare with my contact and it's working fine

Comment: Happy to hear, you have fixed by yourself.. Happy coding!!